# PagedList error when passing Data with Viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, pagedlist

Hi I was wondering if anyone con shed some light with a problem that I´m experiencing when implementing pagedlist code (https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) in my asp.net mvc3 website. This are the details of what I´m trying to do:

I created a Viemodel with this details:

```
public class ProductViewModelList
{
    public List<Product> ProductBrowse { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfProducts { get; set; } 
    public List<Category> CategoryModel { get; set; } 
}
```

Then a Controller holding the information that I want to pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult List(int categoryid, int? page)
{
    const int defaultPageSize = 20;
    int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
    var categoryModel = db.Category.Include("Product").Single(c => c.CategoryId == categoryid);
    var paginatedmodel = categoryModel.Product.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
    var viewModel = new ProductViewModelList
    {
        ProductBrowse = paginatedmodel.ToList(),
        NumberOfProducts = categoryModel.Product.Count()
    };
return View(viewModel);
```

Finally the View that starts with:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList>>
@using Social.Helpers;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

and create a foreach with pager in this way:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="result">
<div class="info_result"><h2><a>@Html.ActionLink(Html.TruncateText(item.Title, 25), "Details", new { id = item.ProductId })</a></h2><p><a>@Html.ActionLink(Html.TruncateText(item.Description, 180), "Details", new { id = item.ProductId })</a></p<a>@String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", item.CreatedOn)</a></div>

<div class="paginacion">@Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount)</div>
```

Information: 1- Im using

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList>>
```

because I need to pass information from the IPagedList and from the ProductViewModelList to the View.

2- If I pass inherits like `<IPagedList<Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList>` I received complete intellisense for IPagedList properties but for Viewmodels NumberofProducts, ProductBrowse, CategoryModel I only receive their names but not ther properties like ProductBrowse.ProductId as an example.

3- I would like to display a URL of the type:
http://www.domain.com/Controller/List?categoryId=2&page=1

4- I dont know what I have to do in order to include object values for

```
Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, ObjectValues for categoryId=2)
```

Sorry if this is a mess to understand, I tried my best in order to explain.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in the title.

Comment: sorry, I didnt mean to do that, I will edit. brgds!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList>>
```

try:

```
@model IPagedList<Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList>
```

Also instead of writing foreach loops in your views you could use a display template. So in your view:

```
<div class="result">
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
<div class="paginacion">
    @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount)
</div>
```

and inside `~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/ProductViewModelList.cshtml`

```
@model Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList
<div class="info_result">
    <h2>
        @Html.ActionLink(
            Html.TruncateText(Model.Title, 25), 
            "Details", 
            new { id = Model.ProductId }
        )
    </h2>
    <p>  
        @Html.ActionLink(
            Html.TruncateText(Model.Description, 180), 
            "Details", 
            new { id = item.ProductId }
        )
    </p>
    <!-- I've modified this to use a display template instead of String.Format
    Now you only need to decorate your view model property with the DisplayFormat attribute like this:
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    -->
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CreatedOn)
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. I tried that but when I do that I lost ProductViewModelList properties and they are not displayed. properties of IPagedList remains - properties such as TotalItemCount but not the others...

Comment: @sebastian_h, that's because your model is `IPagedList<T>` and you will only have properties `PageSize`, `PageNumber` and `TotalItemCount` in the main view. It's only when you start enumerating or using a display template as in my example that you will see the properties for each item of the collection.

Comment: @Darin_Dimitrov great approach, thank you so much. I made those changes and I have intellisense. On the other hand I receive the following error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Social.Helpers.IPagedList`1[Social.ViewModels.ProductViewModelList]'. Do you know how can I pass ObjectValues for categoryId=2 in the Html.Pager area from the controller?. brgds

Comment: @sebastian_h, I see. Your controller action returns an instance of `ProductViewModelList` and not `IPagedList<ProductViewModelList>`. You will need to modify it so that it returns the proper view model type.

Comment: @Darin_Dimitrov I will see what can I do, probably create a call to category. Thank you so much for your responses. for me the answer shed light on many approaches!. brgds

Answer (score 1):

You can try another library [PagedListExt](http://www.calabonga.com/Blog/ViewPost.aspx?id=88). It can be installed by [nuget-pakage](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/PagedListExt)

Comment: great, do you have an ajax pager also in your webpage? I check your blog but russian its was hard for me and translate was not so accurate.. additional info greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes. You can see the code sample in my blog [PagedList with Ajax.](http://www.calabonga.com/Blog/ViewPost.aspx?id=89)